# Uninstall package

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed a package via

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

How do I uninstall this package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in case you want to remove also configuration files use:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

if you want to keep configuration files (because you want to re-install it later using the old config):

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-restricted-extras
```