# Remove smartmontools ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to uninstall a package](https://superuser.com/questions/202215/how-to-uninstall-a-package)

I have installed smartmontools on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

but I accidently installed it in the wrong server window, does anyone know how to uninstall it? I have to tried to google the answer but have found now way of removing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to how you ran `apt-get install`, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove smartmontools
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, never thought it'd be that easy, I also now feel like an idiot